# Android adding dynamically View in RemoteViews show only the first view! How I can change layout_alignParentBottom from code?

Tags: android, layout, view, alignment, remoteview

How I can add dynamically a View in a Relative layout using a cicle like `for`?

This is my code:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_1);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            RemoteViews newView = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.element);
            newView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_toggle, R.drawable.bt_close_n);
            remoteViews.addView(R.id.layout_1, newView);

    }
            int statusIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            notification = new Notification(statusIcon, c.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), System
                    .currentTimeMillis());
            notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

            notification.contentView = remoteViews;

            nm.notify(3,notification);
```

I know that "A child of the view being added had the attribute layout_alignParentBottom="true", which caused it to fill the whole parent, blocking any additional children. Removing the attribute allowed the other children to appear".

So how I can set layout_alignParentBottom="false"??
Many thanks at all...

Comment: what are you tryng to do here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do here but perhaps you're after a ListView.